# Swagger cannot apply to Interfaces

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, resteasy, swagger

We separte de REST definitions on Interfaces like:

```
    public inteface Bitacora { ... }
```

and then implementations goes:

```
    public class BitacoraResource implements Bitacora { ... }
```

after a lot of testing we saw that Swagger works only if the definition IS a class a not and interface.

**Is there a solution to make Swagger used the interfaces rather than classes?**

```
@Provider
@Path("/bitacora")
@Api(value = "/bitacora", description = "API")
public class Bitacora {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Wrapped(element="bitacora")
    @GZIP
    @ApiOperation(value = "obtiene info",notes = "obtiene info bitacora",consumes="*/*",produces= "*/*")
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "ok"),@ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "sinlistar"), @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "error") })
    public Collection<Favorito> listar(@HeaderParam("data") String data) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use?

Comment: The version is 1.3.9 the file is : swagger-core_2.10-1.3.9.jar

Comment: In version 1.3.12 that case is supported, here is sample project: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/v1.3.12/samples/java-resteasy-spring/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/resource/UserResource.java
And here is closed issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/562

Comment: @glw is right. This has been resolved a long time ago. I'd highly recommend switching to the 1.5 branch too.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot interact with the REST Endpoint, then the Endpoint does not comply to OpenAPI (Swagger) specification. Swagger should include working endpoints which can be made possible only by classes and not interfaces.

Refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60679121/3009968) to other question for details.